# Update ComboBox value with new table entry

Tags: ms-access, vba

I insert a new table entry via a second form and then want to update the selected ComboBox value of the first form.
Using the macro method SetProperty Forms!FirstForm!ComboBox with Value = [Forms]![SecondForm]![ID].
If I debug the value of the ComboBox, the command seems to correctly set the value of the ComboBox , however, the ID displayed is still the old value.
What can I do? A refresh doesnt help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have absolutely no idea why this doesn't work with macros, however, it works without problems when using a function instead:

```
Forms!FirstForm!ID.Requery
Forms!FirstForm!ID.Value = Me.ID
```

Comment: You need to use: 1) `Requery` action in macro (referencing the other form's combo box) and 2) `SetValue` action (again, referencing other form's combo box and setting expression to current form's ID control). Also note; SetValue is only available under the Show All Actions catalog since it is a cautionary action as it changes data.

Comment: SetValue... I missed that. Thanks!